# jqGrid Column Reordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to get column reordering working in jqGrid 3.8.1, I have sortable set to true (in the actual options not the colModel), I'm importing the full jquery UI (including sortable and draggable/droppable).

Despite this the columns refuse to reorder, I can't drag them at all and I get no errors in IE or chrome inspectors. I've viewed multiple guides and tried to use the code from http://www.trirand.net/examples/functionality/column_reorder_resize/ (including the js in view source).

Any ideas on what could be causing this to not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved to be the release version that I was using. I was using 3.8.1 and an update to 4.1.1 fixed it.